# Keep the data updated in React

Tags: json, reactjs, rest

I could not find something specific about what I'm trying to understand.

I want to know what is the best pratice to keep the data always updated. For example, using React, you will fetch the data of something using an API, then you will work with the state to keep the data updated for the user on the screen. But let's think that it is a software in which are other people working in the same "database". How may I keep this data updated from external changes?

I know it is possible to use things like a React Lifecycle Method to updated or even setTimeOut to request a new json. But there is other way to do something similar to Firebase Realtime database?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I've used sockets.io to broadcast updates to connected React clients.  Server side I have a 'job' tied into a setTimeout function.  Every time the job runs, it broadcasts the results to the client.  It should be straightforward to detect a data change and then fire that to the clients.

Comment: Thank you! I've already heard about socket, but I forgot about it. Socket.io is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Good stuff, neat tool and straightforward to implement.